# Face verification cognitive services

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services

We have a requirement where we are in need to implement face verification through cognitive services. I have been following below mentioned link.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Face-Verification-c1995f48

When execution comes at tGet.Wait(), system got hanged and never executed next line.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45OeT.png)

Comment: Please don't post your code as screenshot, instead add the code directly to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your application, you may have a synchronization context in play, and the current implementation of the client library will result in the deadlock you describe.  [Here's](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) a pretty decent writeup on contexts.

The workaround I would suggest is the following:

```
var task = Task.Run(async () => {
  try {
     await Clnt.GetPersonGroupAsync(groupId);
  } catch {
     await Clnt.CreatePersonGroupAsync(groupId, groupName);
  }
  // Use the PersonGroup
);
```